# IP address/range filter for Azure Service Bus

Tags: security, azure, azureservicebus, acs

We are implementing a solution which involves third party systems accessing our Azure Service Bus, secured by SAS. As long as this SAS is secure, we're happy :)

But we want to limit the impact should the SAS be compromised. For Azure Storage, an SAS can be issued with an IP range filter which helps, but this is not supported for service bus.

Is there any way to limit access to the service bus based on IP address? This is especially an issue, in our case, for third party systems who should read from the service bus.

Would switching to ACS (which is an option for other reasons) help in any way?

Comment: Which Azure ACS do you mean? Azure Container Services? Access Control Service

Comment: Sorry for not specifying, ErikOppedijk: Access Control Service

Answer (score 3):

Myself I am still searching for a way to restrict access to Service Bus to certain IP range. Until than I have found recommendation of scenario that has to certain level similar effect.

First part of the idea is to make SAS tokens very short lived like half an hour or less. Second is not to store those SAS tokens in source and configuration, but make rest service that hands them out. Now that Token factory and handout service can be secured, and among other measures with restricted IP address.

Now with SAS tokens out of configuration and source files they are less likely to leak, and there is much shorter time frame they can be abused.

Now there is a cost with more moving parts, but it seems not too steep price. And idea of getting rid of security tokens out of config is well probably well worth on its own.

I have found [the idea described here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2012/06/12/introducing-table-sas-shared-access-signature-queue-sas-and-update-to-blob-sas/)

It is a bit old (at least in cloud years), and there are some new developments like Azure Key vault, and maybe it can be used to make scenario better or easier.

Comment: This is similar to what we've come up with as a workaround (just using the Key Vault, as you suggest). It was just hoping there was a simpler solution and I don't see why IP filtering isn't a standard part of Service Bus authorization. But I guess there are no simpler solutions...

Answer (score 2):

Update: Azure Service Bus now has a preview of IP Filtering for Service Bus Premium and Event Hubs:

> This feature allows users to control which IPs are accessing their
>   resources. Some characteristics of this feature:
>
> - Rules allow you to specify accept and reject actions on IP masks.
> - The rules work with IPv4 addresses.
> - Rules are applied to the namespace level.
> - You can have multiple rules and they are applied in order.
> - The first rule that matches the IP address determines the accept or reject
>     action.
> - Requests from IPs that are rejected receive an unauthorized response.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/ip-filtering-for-event-hubs-and-service-bus/

Alternative solution:
You can add Azure API management in front of your service. 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-get-started/

Azure API management offers:

- IP blocking  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn894078.aspx#RestrictCallerIPs
- rate throttling
- Claims based authentication (JWT)
- Subscription/access to APIs

For an excellent example check out this blog post:
http://blog.brauwers.nl/2014/05/29/exposing-a-service-bus-topic-using-azure-api-management/

For ACS, there is no development going on, most of the functionality is also exposed/moved in Azure AD and Azure B2C.

Comment: Thank you for your input. This could be a solution in some cases, but one I hope to avoid for our case, for two reasons: The number of setup steps would be very high, as we have many integrations using this pattern. Also, we would need the premium edition of API management, which has a hefty price tag.

Comment: My Impression was that API management can be used to expose back end service (which is not otherwise exposed) in controlled manner. And we were hopping to achieve opposite: Hide exposed service.  If one would go  on to do as you have suggested, would not Service Bus remain directly accessible to anyone who has url and SAS token?

Comment: Yes, but you would not share the service bus url with your clients. Another option is to add the SAS in api management, and let users sign in with API management credentials, so they dont even have the SAS

Comment: We are talking about additional protection in case service bus URL and SAS credentials get in wrong hands.

Comment: If you are worried about the URL and SAS getting in wrong hands, that's a different problem. Don't expose them (but then you have the same problem with the API management URL and keys) rotate the keys every day/month might help

Comment: Just to be clear, if you put API Management as another layer, you can still go around the Management service and hit the bus directly.

Comment: We have the same problem, we have some data that we don't want to expose to entire world, and because the Service Bus don't have and IP address restriction, we can't use the service as we want.